# How to use the javascript and Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) for both IE(Internet Explorer) and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

WE are Medium based product Company,Now our product using javascript and CSS (Cascading Style Sheet)are supported only the IE compatible browser(IE 6,7),but some of the script aren't supported the FireFox.

What WE need ?

I need the javascript and Cascading Style Sheet(CSS) to use both the IE and especially the Mozilla FireFox.
Can you clarify the doubts ?
We are fully migrate our product to support with Mozilla FireFox.
Suppose did you know any new technology to overcome the issue. Please recommend it.
I need anybody help..........

Comment: I have no idea what he's asking

Answer (score 2):

By targeting "Firefox" you are simply repeating a past mistake. You need to target HTML / ECMA / CSS standards and make adjustments only where an obvious browser limitation or bug prevents standards compliance. There are numerous tools to ensure compliance.

As a general rule any code that does `IsBrowser(browserName)` is fundamentally broken and should be replaced by `DoesBrowserHaveFeature(featureName)` <- Note that these are not real Javascript functions, see references for how to detect features.

There are libraries like jQuery that can handle some browser differences for you. You will still need to update your code.

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser
- http://www.webdevelopersjournal.com/articles/cross_browser/javascript.html
- http://friendlybit.com/css/cross-browser-strategies-for-css/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript
- http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/ (HTML/CSS Validation Tools)

Comment: sorry we are'nt understanding what are you trying to said...

Comment: Then you need to develop an understanding of the benefits of standards compliance. It is standards that allow different browsers to handle the same code. Your site does not follow standards or it would work in Firefox, Opera, Chrome already.

Comment: hello spliff,thank you for ur reply. Where it exactly locates...can you give me that

Comment: I don't understand your comment. There are no easy answers, you need to make an effort to understand which parts of your code are not standards compliant and replace them with code that is. Your original question is far too vague to be answered directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the Web Standards. Your site must be using code that is proprietary to microsoft at some moments and thats something that must be avoided, as the world is walking forward to a fully open web. Its not just that your website wont open in firefox. It wont open in safari, chrome, opera, TVs, Mobiles, iPhones, iPads, Androids, BlackBerries and so on. And also will not be as catchable by search engine crawlers as your concorrents website.

What I suggest you to do is to start trying http://validator.w3.org/ in all your website pages and make it totally valid. So then, you may have issues with internet explorer 6, 7, 8, because is a browser that constantly avoid following the w3c rules. Thats when the exceptions will come in your code and i personally like to tune then with jquery, because it has a lot of good functions for it.

I hope my answer helps.